# Angular2 component inside bootstrap-select data-content attribute does not render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I've got a hybrid Angular 1/2 web app that uses [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) (BS) for selects. With it you can set a `data-content` attribute on `<option>` elements that BS takes and inserts into the select options (with `<ul>` and `<li`> elements).

I've got the following Angular2 components:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-select',
    template: `
        <select>
            <option data-content="<my-other-component></my-other-component> Foo Bar">Foo Bar</option>
        </select>`
})
export class MySelectComponent {}
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-other-component',
    template: '<span>Hello</span>',
})
export class MyOtherComponent {}
```

As you can see there's a component in the `data-content` attribute in the template for `MySelectComponent`. However, it does not get processed by Angular2.

The select itself is picked up by BS properly and generates a nicely styled select, but the component inside the `data-content` isn't parsed. The generated HTML for the option looks like this:

```html
<li><my-other-component></my-other-component> Foo Bar</li>
```

... instead of this:

```html
<li><span>Hello</span> Foo Bar</li>
```

I know this is a bit of a specific question, but has anyone run into this before or have any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `import` your component and also include your `component` inside `directives meta-data` like below:

```
import {MyOtherComponent} from '.app/my-other-component.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-select',
    template: `
        <select>
            <option data-content="<my-other-component></my-other-component> Foo Bar">Foo Bar</option>
        </select>`,
    directives: [MyOtherComponent]
})
export class MySelectComponent {}
```

Comment: "directives" seems to be no longer supported and was replaced by "entryComponents", but even when I add that it doesn't fix my issue. I'm on Angular 2.1.0.